# Can I use robots.txt to allow Google to access some folders, but disallow everything else?

Tags: googlebot, robots.txt, folder, disallow

I want to allow Google bots to crawl only my index.php and the content of some folders. Would that work?

```
User-agent: *

Allow: /index*.php
Allow: /folder1/
Allow: /folder2/
Allow: /folder3/
Allow: /folder4/

Disallow: /
```

The idea is for Google to crawl URLs like:

- `http://example.com/folder1/discussionA/topic/`
- `http://example.com/folder1/discussionB/topic/`
- `http://example.com/folder1/discussionC/topic/`
- `http://example.com/folder2/discussionD/topic/`

and exclude everything else.

Comment: What is the idea behind the `*` in `/index*.php`?

Comment: You say Google, but use `User-agent: *`. Do you want to target only Google’s bot, or any bot?

Answer (score 1):

I generally focus on what I don't want them to crawl, but I think your sample seems on target. I would, however, remove the space between the first line and the second:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /index*.php
Allow: /folder1/
```

[Mozilla explains it in more detail](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt)